# How to tell if Win32_NTLogEvent InsertionString exists?

Tags: windows, events, vbscript, wmi

I have created a VBScript to diplay my System Log contents. I want to also include the InsertionString, if it exists.  However, I can't seem to determine whether there is an InsertionString or not.  Here is the beginning of my script:

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
Set rs = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_NTLogEvent Where Logfile = 'System' and SourceName = 'mysource'")
For Each objEvent in rs
    If objEvent.InsertionString exists....
```

I have tried several variations to determine if there is an InsertionString, but without success, including:

```
If Not IsNull(objEvent.InsertionString) Then
If objEvent.InsertionString.Length > 0 Then
If GetLength(objEvent.InsertionString(1)) > 0 Then
If objEvent.InsertionString(1).Length > 0 Then
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misspelling in the property name `InsertionString` should be [`InsertionStrings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394226%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
 So this code will work fine

```
 If not IsNull(objEvent.InsertionStrings) Then
```

Note : The `InsertionStrings` property is an array of strings, so you can iterate over that property using a `For Each` loop or the [`UBound`](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_ubound.asp) and [`LBound`](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_lbound.asp?output=print) functions.

Comment: `LBound()` is normally rather useless, since the lower bound is always 0 in VBScript arrays.

Comment: @RRUZ, thanks for the reply. I used InsertionStrings in the script but accidentally wrote InsertionString here.  
Unfortunately objEvent.InsertionStrings is always Not Null whether there is an insertion string or not. So when I refer to objEvent.InsertionStrings(1) I get an Invalid Index error.

Comment: @Neilw, the array is zero index based, so try  using `objEvent.InsertionStrings(0)` and check the bounds of the array with the UBound and LBound functions.

Comment: @RRUZ, that seems to be the ticket. Thanks!